# How to fix `set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1` in this case?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im following this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html

After trying to implement it, I encountered this error when opening the `index.html` link from the Object URL on the file info page.

> There was an error listing your albums: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1

I've searched stackoverflow for similar questions but it seems that this is a different situation as I just uploaded my `index.html` and `photoview.js` files to the s3 bucket. I dont know where `~/.aws/credentials` is as some answers mentioned.

[image]

The bucket structure is shown as in the pic.

PS: Im not really familiar with Cognito but Im following the tutorial.

I create an identity pool as it suggested, and then found the IAM role for the unauthenticated identity and use the policy created to add permissions to this identity.

Finally, as in the Configuring the SDK section, I replaced this code with the sample code as suggested in the annotation by replacing `REGION` & `IDENTITY_POOL_ID` with the actual values.

```
//   Cognito -- Manage Identity Pools -- [identity_pool_name] -- Sample Code -- JavaScript
//
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'REGION'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
});
```

Comment: What a nightmare for a simple website. It is for learning, for fun or for a company?

Comment: @user900476, it worked for me, could you please share your index.html and PhotoViewer.js. I guess the main issue is related to the bucket access policy.